Integral equivariant formality for Hamiltonian T-actions
What is the simplest example of a compact symplectic manifold $M$ with Hamiltonian $T$-action for which the integral $T$-equivariant cohomology is not formal
i.e. $$H_T^*(M,\mathbb{Z}) \not \cong H^*(M,\mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H^*(BT,\mathbb{Z})? $$
It is a well-known theorem (due to Atiyah-Bott-Kirwan) that the analogous formality theorem holds rationally.

So you couldn't believe a result that you've just proved and asked to see if anyone knows a counterexample?
